# Maintaining iOS app for different countries in one Git repository

Tags: iphone, ios, git, version-control, app-store

Our team released an app in China and right now we are going to add lot's of new features and release it in many other countries too.

The problem is that it's hardly possible to localize it inside of one app - it's a language learning app, with a language-dependent pre-populated database, different social networks and other stuff, so we decided to release different apps for different countries. Is this a right(or at least possible - i mean, will Apple approve it) approach?

If it is, then how can we maintain different version of app for different countries in one repository, while working on the core features?

What kind of branching will do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new target and (for instance) specify different preproccessor macro's, info-plist files and more so you can identify the localized target.

Comment: Thank you, just didn't think of targets - had no experience of that.What about ditributing it all in different stores?Is that ok?

Comment: The best way is to make 1 app where you can switch languages (for app store ratings etc). But if you create multiple targets, you automatically get multiple apps. I don't see any problems in creating different apps for different languages.